# How to generate the output directory for a Nextflow process within the docker container?

Tags: docker, nextflow

I am running two processes (as given below) in the nextflow script. The first process is outputting some plots which must be included by the second process to generate a pdf file. Both these processes are run inside a docker container (docimage:1.0.0). When I run this nextflow script the first process runs fine but the second process is not completed because the latex file can't find the plots since the output directory containing plots is not created inside the docker container. The output directory containing plots is however generated in the local directory from where the nextflow script is run.
Could someone suggest how to generate the output directory from the first process inside the docker container as well so that latex file can include the plots from within the docker container? Thanks !

```
process run_pr {

echo true
container 'docimage:1.0.0'

publishDir "${params.outDir}", mode: 'copy'

output:
file '*' into output_ch

script:
"""
Rscript /home/project/scripts/run.R -s "$params.inputDir" -i "$params.inputFile"
"""
}



process latexGen {

echo true
container 'docimage:1.0.0'

input:
file '*' from output_ch

output:
publishDir "${params.outDir}", mode: 'copy'
    
script:
"""
pdflatex -output-directory=/home/project/$params.outDir  /home/project/scripts/doc.tex
"""
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Best to avoid using absolute paths referencing files in your pipeline processes. You need to make sure the input files get localized correctly. This might help get you started:

```
inputFile = file(params.inputFile)
inputDir = file(params.inputDir)

tex = file('/home/project/scripts/doc.tex')

process run_pr {

    container 'docimage:1.0.0'

    publishDir "${params.outDir}/run_pr", mode: 'copy'

    input:
    file inputFile
    file inputDir

    output:
    file '*' into output_ch // avoid using loose wildcards when specifying outputs

    script:
    """
    run.R -s "${inputDir}" -i "${inputFile}"
    """
}

process latexGen {

    container 'docimage:1.0.0'

    publishDir "${params.outDir}/latexGen", mode: 'copy'

    input:
    file 'pdf/*' from output_ch
    file tex

    output:
    file "pdf/doc.pdf"
    
    script:
    """
    pdflatex -output-directory pdf doc.tex
    """
}
```

My experience with latex is limited. It's not completely clear to me how the `-output-directory` option works:

```
-output-directory directory
    Write output files in directory instead of the current directory.
    Look up input files in directory first, the along the normal search path.
```

If your output directory is being used to output the PDF, you can ignore the option. If it is being used to 'look up' input files, then you'll obviously need to keep it.

It's also not completely clear what your process 'run_pr' does and what it's outputs are. Does it write just one file or does it produce multiple files? If you could clarify with some example inputs, that would be super.

Comment: Sorry for commenting late on you post. Thank you for your suggestions and guidelines. I will modify the config file and main.nf file accordingly. Also, considering the time constraints, I have implemented a make-shift solution in which I have merged the two processes into a single process. The output is generated as required. Cheers !